# Assign data to RadGrid

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I want to have a grid with two columns, one with title and the second with two hyper links (if it is easier, you can create 2 different columns, one for each link).

I have an array of the titles and an array of ids. I want that the link will be something like "edit.aspx?id=INSERT_ID_FROM_DATA_HERE".

What I have so far:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" Skin="Telerik" AutoGenerateColumns="True">
                                            <MasterTableView>
                                                <Columns>
                                                    <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Title" UniqueName="Title" DataFormatString="'{0}'">
                                                    </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
                                                    <telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn HeaderText="Actions" UniqueName="Actions" 
                                                        DataNavigateUrlFormatString="default.aspx?id='{0}" DataTextField="Edit">
                                                    </telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn>
                                                </Columns>
                                            </MasterTableView>
                                        </telerik:RadGrid>
```

AND:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataColumn dcTitle = new DataColumn("Title");
            DataColumn dcId = new DataColumn("Actions");
            dt.Columns.Add(dcTitle);
            dt.Columns.Add(dcId);

            String[] widgetNames = new String[list.Count];
            String[] widgetIds = new String[list.Count];

            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                widgetNames[i] = list[i].SelectSingleNode("title").InnerText;
                widgetIds[i] = list[i].SelectSingleNode("instanceid").InnerText;

                String[] row = new String[2];
                row[0] = widgetNames[i];
                row[1] = widgetIds[i];

                dt.LoadDataRow(row, true);
            }

            RadGrid1.DataSource = dt;
```

It creates 2 new columns and just prints the titles and ids there, without the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are specifying columns, be sure to set AutoGenerateColumns="False".
Set the DataField and DataNavigateUrlFields attributes to the column names of your data source.

The placeholder values in the data format strings refer to the specified data fields for a grid column. A GridBoundColumn can only have one DataField, but the GridHyperLinkColumn can have multiple data fields separated by commas; {0} refers to the first field, {1} to the second, etc...

To answer your question about multiple hyperlinks, it is easier to use a separate GridHyperLinkColumn for each one. Otherwise you would have to use a TemplateColumn to write your own completely custom rendering.

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid1" runat="server" Skin="Telerik" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <MasterTableView>
        <Columns>
            <telerik:GridBoundColumn HeaderText="Title" DataField="Title" DataFormatString="'{0}'" />
            <telerik:GridHyperLinkColumn HeaderText="Actions" UniqueName="Actions" DataNavigateUrlFields="Actions" DataNavigateUrlFormatString="default.aspx?id='{0}'" DataTextField="Edit" />
        </Columns>
    </MasterTableView>
</telerik:RadGrid>
```

Comment: Thanks! The title works, but the actions tab doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Has your DataSource changed since you posted the question? You'll have to provide some more information in order to troubleshoot the reason the hyperlink column isn't working. The way the datasource is being built seems overly complicated. It can be simplified.